# asp mvc - opera return 401 response when sended ajax NTLM request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, opera, ntlm, http-status-code-401

I have web app (asp.net mvc mvc 4), when i enable ntlm authentification in visual studio and try to send ajax request for example `$.ajax({url : 'http://localhost:4135/'});` the returned server response is 401 - and it happens only on opera, chrome work fine, and firefox. Who can help to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, see my post on Opera dev forums - http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1546222&t=1350032501  Nobody keens to answer it however.

Comment: I simply don't have any NTLM authentication environment to test this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that they fixed the bug in Opera 12.10.